# Series representation for a specific range

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I am wondering if there is a valid series representation using:

$f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k(z-z_0)^k$

for $r<|z−z_0|<R$

Why is this not possible?

Comment: It was a typo, I have fixed it!

Comment: A function of this form is called analytic. In particular you can see that such function has to be continuous. So any non-continuous function can't take that form.

Comment: Would this function satisfy the requirements? I think it does since it is from negative infinity to positive infinity

Comment: I might misinterpret the question. I understand it as follows "why it isn't possible to express every function as $f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k(z-z_0)^k$". If this is what you meant then the answer is that the sum is always continuous.

Comment: Does that mean that as long as the function is continuous we can represent it using that sum?

Comment: No, it needs to be analytic. This is a stronger version of continuity (it is equivalent to being differentiable infinitely many times). You should read the Wikipedia article about Analytic functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function (Just make sure not to confuse real analytic and complex analytic)

Comment: That is called a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).